# To set a bool value if any of the column in empty in Sql Table using Linq in C#?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to get the details from the table using LINQ in C# and the where condition is ID and here my condition is ,if any of the column in the selected row is empty or null i need to return as False if not means True should be returned.....Cn any one help for this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table has the following columns: `ID`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`. You can the use the following Linq statement.

```
bool anyIsNull = (from row in context.Table
                  where row.ID = id
                  select (row.Col1 == null || row.Col2 == null ||
                          row.Col3 == null || row.Col4 == null).Single();
```